# How to change my name on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I registered as, say John Doe, and then later on, created a YouTube presence with a name such as "Cool Gaming Channel" and a channel also with that name.

Yet after I published a video, and I viewed it, the name displayed is "John Doe" and I couldn't find a way to change it. How can it be changed to "Cool Gaming Channel"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign in to your channel on YouTube.
2. Click your account icon > settings .
3. In the "Overview" section, click Edit on Google next to your channel name.
4. Update the channel name and click OK.

from: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en